# emacs identation works only in terminal (-nw)

Tags: emacs, indentation, emacs23, cperl-mode

I have GNU Emacs 23.1.1, on Ubuntu 10.10.

I have to following .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
  '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
)

(show-paren-mode 1)
(setq show-paren-delay 0)

;; perl mode stuff
(fset 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
(setq cperl-indent-level 4
      cperl-close-paren-offset -4
      cperl-continued-statement-offset 0
      cperl-indent-parens-as-block t
      cperl-tab-always-indent t
      cperl-invalid-face nil
)
```

When I do `$ emacs -nw` the tab indentation works fine. When I launch the GUI version with `$ emacs` tab indentation doesn't work. I only get space indentation.

How can I get tab indentation in the GUI as well?

The cperl conf was taken from [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPerl)

The emacs packages I have:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep emacs
ii  emacs                                23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2+maverick1                       The GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
ii  emacs-goodies-el                     33.6ubuntu1                                       Miscellaneous add-ons for Emacs
ii  emacs-snapshot                       1:20090909-1                                      The GNU Emacs editor (development snapshot)
ii  emacs-snapshot-bin-common            1:20090909-1                                      The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs-snapshot-common                1:20090909-1                                      The GNU Emacs editor's common infrastructure
ii  emacs23                              23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2+maverick1                       The GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user interface)
ii  emacs23-bin-common                   23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2+maverick1                       The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs23-common                       23.1+1-4ubuntu7.2+maverick1                       The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacsen-common                       1.4.19ubuntu1                                     Common facilities for all emacsen
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, but I just noticed that I hadn't studied the behaviour correctly. In both gui and -nw, when I edit a file already indented in tabs, it uses tabs, whereas when I edit a new file, it indents it with spaces.

Comment: what is the result of `C-h w <TAB>`?

Comment: @kindahero: in the GUI right? the result is a the prompt of the "where is command" and a list of possible commands (I guess due to the <TAB>)

Comment: sorry, that should be `C-h k <TAB>` (C-h k tells you "the command" runs by the key stroke)

Comment: @kindahero Hm, there seems to be something. In the GUI `indent-for-tab-command`
In the -nw `forward-button`.

Although see my edit for a mistake I had made.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the `*Messages*` and `*Warnings*` buffers on startup.  There might be a hint as to what's failing there.  In particular, `*Messages*` should list all the startup files that emacs is loading; on Ubuntu, this will include files in `/etc/emacs` as well as your `.emacs`.

If that doesn't help, try running your .emacs interactively in the emacs debugger.  Start emacs with `emacs -nw -q` and load .emacs into a buffer.  Run <kbd>M-x edebug-all-forms</kbd> then run <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd>.  Press space repeatedly to step through the file.

Edit: Check the value of `indent-tabs-mode` in a perl buffer in both of your environment.  This is used to control whether to indent with tab characters or spaces.  Adding `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)` should force emacs to indent with tab characters.

Comment: `*Messages*`: has nothing suspicious (all `done`). I don't have a `*Warnings*` buffer and I couldn't find how to open it.

I also tried the other thing, but the debugger reported what was returned from each command and finished happily.

Comment: I added `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)` before the `;; perl mode stuff`, but it didn't change anything. 

However, see my edit for a mistake I had made.